# Not able to parse response in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

i am getting the following response from my PHP script.

PHP:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","pass","products");

if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect database, please check with your administrator. Error is <br />" . mysqli_connect_errno();
}   

$cat = $_POST['cat'];
$text = "this is from php server";
$json = array();
$html = ''; 
if ($cat == 'designer'){
    $query = " select * from shirts where category_1 = '$cat'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {

        $html .= "<div class='des-result'>" . $row['code'] ."</div>";
    }
}

if ($cat == 'regular'){
    $query = " select * from shirts where category_2 = '$cat'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $html .= "<div class='des-result'>" . $row['code'] ."</div>";
    }
}

$json[] = array(
    'html' => $html,
    'text' => $text
);

header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo json_encode($json);

?>
```

jQuery:

```
$("body").on("click",".reg", function (){
    $(".des-result").remove();
    $(".reg-result").remove();
    db_name = "shirts";
    category = "regular";
    var data = {

           cat : category
    };
    $.ajax ({
            type:"POST",
            url:"data.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: data,
            success: function(res) {

                                    $("#result").append(res.html);
                                   console.log(res.text);

                                   },
            error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
                console.log(xhr);
                console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
      }
    });
```

Below is the output on console (using firebug) when i click on the div

```
 [Object { html="<div class='des-result'>...es-result'>pk-004</div>", text="this is from php server"}]
```

I thought i would be able to access text and html variables like this. res.html and res.text but it shows undefined if i console log it.

Please guide what i am dong wrong here

Comment: Have you tried $parseJSON? http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Comment: have you tried outputting res to the console to ensure you're getting back what you were expecting?

Comment: Yes and i have also pasted the result. To me it looks fine but this is the first time i am working with JSON.

Comment: yeah i tried JSON (not working) but i am getting JSON in proper format so i dont think i need that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the way you are returning the array, correct result would be res.0.html since you are making it a multidimensional array.

```
$json[] = array(
    'html' => $html,
    'text' => $text
);
```

It should instead read:

```
$json = array(
    'html' => $html,
    'text' => $text
);
```

Then res.html would return the "html" as long as the json is what's returned..

Comment: i was also able to get it working via $.each function. But i really wanted your method. Thanks alot, i will mark it correct, i dont know why its not allowing me right now